# PHP class extends a public variable

Tags: php

I have two classes

```
class validate {
    public $mediaFlag;

    function ValidateTypeOfMedia($SOEmag,$SOEtab,$Soct,$DAL,$insertMeda,$other){    
        if($SOEmag==""){
            return "Must select Media Type";
        }
        else{
            $this->mediaFlag=1;
        }
    }

    function whatever()
    {
        if( $this->mediaFlag==1)
        {
            echo "flag is here";
        }
        else {
            echo "flag didn't work";
        }
    }
}/// Class validate Ends


class InsertINDB extends validate 
{

    function test(){
        if( $this->mediaFlag==1)
        {
            echo "flag is here";
        }
        else {
            echo "flag didn't work";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is in class insertINDB , function test does not recognize that the mediaFlag variable has been set...however, function whatever in the parent class does recognize  so. so my question, how come function test in class InsertINDB does not know that the flag has been set in the parent class.

```
$object_validate= new validate;

$object_DB= new InsertINDB;

$object_validate->whatever();
$object_DB->test();
```

Comment: how you call InsertINDB?

Comment: Did you set it to 1? If not, method ValidateTypeOfMedia() has to be called before (which sets it to 1 if the string is empty)

Comment: `$var = new InsertINDB(); $var->ValidateTypeOfMedia(1,1,1,1,1,1); $var->test();` - still not working? [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mlxETk)...

Comment: @Laxus i just updated the post on I called them.

Comment: Please don't get this the wrong way, I sincerely think you should read a bit more about OOP and especially how it's implemented in PHP. Fixing your code won't fix the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is a misunderstanding of how extending classes works, and the difference between classes and objects.

When you do `$var = new ClassName` you instantiate an object based on the class. This object is no longer connected to the class directly, and changing a value in another instance from the same class does not affect the other instances.

The same principal applies to classes which extend other classes - once instantiated, an object stands separate from every other object, regardless of whether they are from the same class or one of it's parents/children.

Let's take a simple example:

```
class Bob {

  public $property = 1;

}

class Dave extends Bob {
}

$bob = new Bob;
$dave = new Dave;

echo $bob->property; // 1
echo $dave->property; // 1

$bob->property = 2;

echo $bob->property; // 2
echo $dave->property; // 1
```

The behaviour you are expecting can be obtained by using [*static*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) members (also sometimes known as *class* members).

I think it would be worth you going back to the manual and re-reading the [OOP chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in full.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see - in the case where the flag is set, something has set it - there is no default value. The problem is not in the extending of `validate`, you just don't set the public property to any value before accessing it in `InsertINDB`. Eg in the first case `ValidateTypeOfMedia` is called, in the second, not.

edit: OR `$SOEma == ""` in the second case evaluates to true and the `ValidateTypeOfMedia` does not set the flag to 1.

BTW imho your code does not look right, not best practice, whatever you are trying to achieve (by no means trying to insult you).

edit2:

What is the result from those, I bet in both cases flag is not set:

```
$object_validate= new validate;

$object_DB= new InsertINDB;

$object_validate->whatever();

$object_DB->test();
```

edit3:

Khanquered Pro, based on your comment - you maybe do not understand the purpose of polymorphism. So to explain - after you extend the first class, you create an instance of the child (in your case InsertINDB). Then that instance holds all the methods (functions) and properties of validate. You can not first call validate in one instance, then expect its properties to be available in the child class - every instance is completely separated thing in this case, they have own property values (state). So after you extend `validate` you only work with the child - use it to validate, use it to insert to db. And you use the partent `validate` only in cases in the application where you need to validate data without inserting anything.

I will not comment on if this whole architecture is good idea - its beyond the scope of the question and probably your current knowledge, but after you succeed with your task, read more on the topic of OOP as a start.

Comment: Someone gave Vesliqs answer a vote down ... but he is right and I voted him up again.

Comment: I saw a -1 at some point as well, someone changed his though obviously :)

Comment: Veseliq, thanks for the input, this is homework by the way. regardless, the purpose of it is two classes, one class will validate the data coming from a form, the 2nd class will insert the data into a db after it get validated... I thought the best way to do it, is make class validate set a flag to let class DB knows that it's ok to put into the DB... however, how you guys suggest something like this can be done. thanks

Comment: @Mike B? You should write a comment on voting up/down - that's what is stated here and what I have done. Also I gave the same answer as Veseliq in my comment and therefor voted him up again.

Comment: @Veseliq please check my last comment.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro, no no! DaveRandom already gave you an excellent answer. Read it, read about OOP, read about PHP OOP. No one will do your homework for you!

Comment: @KhanqueredPro, asking to learn? true. But asking for someone to do your job for you? not a great idea. We're all here to learn (at least I am), so do that.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro, in that case I'm sorry. You're right, this is your question and you have every right to decide who can comment/answer.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro being rude on SO will get you banned. Respect others and work more on your self. Your question was not clear, not constructive, not well explained and you are being rude to the people that point you this.

Comment: it must be that time of the month for some. Thanks all I appreciate  all the answers